# Can Polymorph Any Object turn a human into a Huge Giant with a Permanent duration, with all the benefits of Giant Form II?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, polymorph

Can Polymorph Any Object turn a human into a Huge Giant with a Permanent duration, with all the benefits of Giant Form II?

James Jacobs (Paizo Creative Director) says [on the Paizo forums](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2l7ns&page=653?Ask-James-Jacobs-ALL-your-Questions-Here#32614) in response to someone asking about doing this:

> [Polymorph any object](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/p/polymorph-any-object) can't really do this. You're trying to emulate [giant form II](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/g/giant-form-i) in this case, and [giant] form II isn't an option for polymorph any object, which functions as greater polymorph for the purposes of what it can do, unfortunately.

But the spell states:

> This spell functions like *greater polymorph*, **except that it changes one object or creature into another.**

Based on this wording, is the Polymorph Any Object spell able to grant you the form of a Huge creature with the giant subtype with all the benefits of Giant Form II?

Comment: Can you please provide the link for where James Jacobs said this? I assume its in some FAQ.

Comment: http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2l7ns&page=653?Ask-James-Jacobs-ALL-your-Questions-Here#32614

Comment: [Polymorph spells dont change your creature type](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/125195/21153)

Comment: I know that's why I said "form of a Huge creature". I only mentioned " the giant subtype" due to this line from Polymorph any object "Related (twig is to tree, wolf fur is to wolf, etc.)" and this line "it also allows you to assume the form of any Huge creature of the giant subtype" from giant form II. In Pathfinder Giants and Humans are both Humanoid.

Answer (score 7):

No, it can't. The description of the spell specifically says that it works like *greater polymorph* except that you can turn living creatures into objects and the other way around. Other than that, it mimics *greater polymorph*.

The [description of *greater polymorph*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/p/polymorph/) specifically says that if you use the spell to turn the target into a humanoid creature it works like [*alter self*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/a/alter-self/), which only allows you to take the form of a small or medium humanoid.

Relevant extract from *greater polymorph*:

> If the form is that of a humanoid, the spell functions as alter self.

Relevant extract from *alter self*:

> When you cast this spell, you can assume the form of any Small or Medium creature of the humanoid type.

So you can't use this spell to turn someone into a humanoid bigger than medium. Since giants are humanoids, you can't use it to turn someone into a huge giant.

Comment: "says that it works like greater polymorph except that you can turn living creatures into objects" Are you referring to the first sentence of the spell? Because that's not what it says _specifically_, only that "it changes one object or creature into another".

Comment: @Bainos well, yes, but since polymorph can already change living creatures into other kinds of living creatures,the only difference is that objects get added into the mix. So while I'm not quoting it verbatim, that's specifically said.

Comment: Also, the main point of the sentence you've quoted from my answer is that the spell specifically says that it works like greater polymorph, which is the relevant information. The exception clause is for the sake of completeness. I could put it in parentheses if that helped.