# Does Enlarge Person work on someone under the effect of Polymorph?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, polymorph

A party member casts [polymorph](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/p/polymorph/) on herself.  Will casting [enlarge person](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/e/enlarge-person/) increase her size?

I believe in 3.5 this did not work. I can't find any ruling text in pathfinder saying that it does or doesn't.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## No

On [Magic](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/) on the school [Transmutation](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/#TOC-Transmutation) on the subschool [Polymorph](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/#TOC-Transmutation-Polymorph) says, "In addition, other spells that change your size have no effect on you while you are under the effects of a polymorph [subschool] spell."

An [*enlarge person*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/e/enlarge-person/) spell doesn't work if it's cast on a creature benefiting from a [*polymorph*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/p/polymorph) spell.

Answer (score 0):

I'd want to verify this with your GM, but unless a spell specifically denies a particular tactic, I'd assume the player found a clever use for it and allow it.

Answer (score -1):

## This will work sometimes

Enlarge person can only work on a **humanoid** creature, see spell text. If the party member polymorphs into a humanoid creature (which is allowed), then, enlarge person will enlarge her size. Otherwise (if she polymorphs into a non humanoid creature) it will not enlarge her.

Comment: [(*Pathfinder* transmutation spells don't change a creature's type.)](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/76058/8610)